# How to display multiple record of same type only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3.1.12 application, in which suppose i have a table **A** and in that i have some data and it is associated with table **B** with has_many relationship, i mean to say

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :B, :conditions => {:type => "B"}, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :c, :class_name => "B", :conditions => {:type => nil}, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and in B's model i have :

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :A
end
```

and i have some data in my table **C** which is inherited from **B**

```
 - **name** **amount**
 -    c1      10
 -    c2      20
 -    c3       5
 -    c1      4
 -    c2      15
```

and i want to display this duplicate items only one time something like:

- **name** **amount**

  - c1      14
  - c2      35
  - c3       5

But i don't have any idea how to get this, i have tried `**group_by**` and `uniq` methods but they are not working in my case.In my controller **A** on view action i have declare all this like:

```
class AsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @a = A.find(params[:id])
    @bs = @a.bs
    @cs = @a.cs
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @a }
    end
  end

end
```

and In my view file i have called all these like:

```
<%= render :partial => "b_item_details", :collection => @bs %>

 <%= render :partial => "c_line_item_details", :collection => @cs %>
```

I am sure some might faced such issue, any help would be thankful

Actually i want to display unique records i mean if c1 has 4 entries and c2 has 3 entries than while displaying i want to display c1 and c2 only once and their total should be total of all their entries (c1+c1+c3+c4)

Comment: It's unclear what you want here.  If you only need the unique amounts from the C table, you can do something like `@a.cs.pluck(&:amount).uniq`, which will be very efficient.  If you need the name alongside it, you should be clearer about what you consider to be "duplicate" entries.

Comment: @tyler i have updated my question please have a look, at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@cs = @a.cs.group(:name).sum(:amount)
```

This should return you a hash of name, amount pairs, e.g.:

```
{ 'c1' => 14, 'c2' => 35, 'c3' => 5 }
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#sum

Comment: thanks for reply, but it is not helpful for me, it is just displaying one account but i want to show all other accounts too

Comment: This appears to answer exactly what you asked for.  We have no idea what an "account" is either...

Comment: Thanks @tyler and Steve this gives me hint that is helpful for me